# What's a very simple way to enter key <> value pairs in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a VBA script where I want the following two functionalities (pseudo-code):

```
C5 = "Hello"
D6 = "World"
E2 = 23.45
a: Place the values in the correct cell in the worksheet
and
b: Check if the cells contain the correct values
```

I'll be sharing this with coworkers that have never written a script in their lives (but they are able to use Excel-formulas like vlookup etc). Therefore, I need to be able to very simply write the cell number and the corresponding value next to each other.

```
Sub NewbieProofSub
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "C5", "Hello"
    dict.Add "D6", "World"
    dict.Add "E2", 23.45

    ' Inserting values:
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim s As String
    For Each v In dict.Keys
        s = v
        Range(s).Value = dict.Item(v)
    Next

    dict.Add "F3", 13

    ' Checking values
    For Each v In dict.Keys
        s = v
        If Range(s).Value = dict.Item(v) Then
        MsgBox ("The value in " & s & " is " & dict.Item(v))
        Else
        MsgBox ("The value in " & s & " is not " & dict.Item(v))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

These will be divided into two modules, but I included both here to illustrate.

I'm quite content, but I wonder if it's possible to make it *even simpler*, avoiding all the lines with `dict.add`? Something like:

```
' Fill this list with your desired values on the format:
' Cell, Value (Remove the existing lines)

dict.add {
"C5", "Hello"
"D6", "World"
"E2", 23.45
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Do you want the user to type something in to cell C5 and the words hello appear in D5 ?  Just wondering if simplicity is your aim then can it be done a different way?   you could of course have the dictionary items on another sheet and load it directly from there with a for next loop but I'm guessing that may not make it easier to read for a non programmer..

Comment: Also you know you can add things to a dictionary like this       Dict("F2") ="burp"     this may be very slightly easier to read ??

Comment: I forgot to add the line how  you load a list from a sheet  dict.add Key:=(Range("A1")), Item:=Range("B1")    you don't need the for next loop...

Comment: I didn't know (or I've forgotten) the `Dict("F2") = "burp"` syntax. It might be a bit easier. Having the data in a different sheet is a good idea, byt unfortunately it's not an alternative.

Comment: You may put data into worksheet with syntax like `[C5] = "Hello"` and store that values within `Sub Worksheet_Change()`. After all necessary cells are filled, set a global flag to stop changes processing. Not exactly what you are asking, but that is a simpliest native syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of anything simpler than a single module containing exactly one 
sub, where the Cell-Value pairs are entered just like normal variable assignments:

```
'===============================================================================
' Module     : NewbieProof
' Version    : 1.0
' Part       : 1 of 3
' References : N/A
' Online     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46068523/1961728
'===============================================================================
Sub SuperNewieProofData()

' Fill this list with your desired values in the format:
' Cell = Value (Remove the existing lines)

C5 = "Hello"
D6 = "World"
E2 = 23.45

End Sub
```

---

To enable this sub to be used successfully requires a bit of magic, via the VBA IDE object itself. Think self-modifying code. In this case the code only *reads* the sub from the NewbieProof module, extracting the Cell-Value pairs.

This magic is encapsulated in the helper function `TheNewbieDict()` which returns the fully populated dictionary:

```
'===============================================================================
' Module     : <in any standard module>
' Version    : 1.0
' Part       : 2 of 3
' References : Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3
' Online     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46068523/1961728
'===============================================================================
Private Const l_Error As String = "Error"

Function TheNewbieDict() As Object

  Const l_NewbieProof As String = "NewbieProof"

  Dim e_Proc As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind: e_Proc = VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind.vbext_pk_Proc
  Dim vbprojThis As VBIDE.VBProject
  Dim codeNewbieProof As VBIDE.CodeModule
  Dim strProcName As String
  Dim lngLineNumber As Long
  Dim strCurrentLine As String
  Dim strNewbieCell As String
  Dim strNewbieValue As String

  ' Add reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3"
  On Error Resume Next
  ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=5, Minor:=3
  On Error GoTo 0
  Set TheNewbieDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set vbprojThis = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
  On Error Resume Next: Set codeNewbieProof = vbprojThis.VBComponents(l_NewbieProof).CodeModule: On Error GoTo 0
  If codeNewbieProof Is Nothing Then
    TheNewbieDict.Add l_Error, 1&
    Exit Function
  End If
  With codeNewbieProof
    If .CountOfLines = .CountOfDeclarationLines Then
      TheNewbieDict.Add l_Error, 2&
      Exit Function
    End If
    strProcName = .ProcOfLine(.CountOfDeclarationLines + 1, e_Proc)
    lngLineNumber = .ProcBodyLine(strProcName, e_Proc)
    Do Until lngLineNumber >= .CountOfLines: Do
      lngLineNumber = lngLineNumber + 1
      strCurrentLine = .Lines(lngLineNumber, 1)
      ' Skip comment and empty lines
      If Left$(Trim(strCurrentLine), 1) & "'" Like "'*" Then Exit Do
      ' Skip non-assignment lines ("Function …" and "End Function" lines)
      If Not strCurrentLine Like "*=*" Then Exit Do
      ' Extract the Cell-Value pair from the line
      strNewbieCell = Trim(Replace(Left$(strCurrentLine, InStr(strCurrentLine, "=") - 1), """", ""))
      strNewbieValue = Trim(Replace(Mid$(strCurrentLine, InStr(strCurrentLine, "=") + 1), """", ""))
      If Not TheNewbieDict.Exists(strNewbieCell) Then
        TheNewbieDict.Add strNewbieCell, strNewbieValue
      End If
    Loop While 0: Loop
    If TheNewbieDict.Count = 0 Then
      TheNewbieDict.Add l_Error, 3&
      Exit Function
    End If
  End With

End Function
```

---

And this is how you would call it:

```
'===============================================================================
' Module     : <in any standard module>
' Version    : 1.0
' Part       : 3 of 3
' References : N/A
' Online     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/
'===============================================================================
Sub NOT_NewbieProofSub()

  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set dict = TheNewbieDict()
  If dict.Exists(l_Error) Then
    ' Error creating dictionary - Some newbie deleted/renamed/cleared
    ' or otherwise messed with the NewbieProof code module.
    MsgBox _
      "Oops! Not so newbie-proof!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
      & "Looks like some Newbie " _
      & Choose(dict("Error"), "renamed or delete", "deleted the sub in", "deleted the data from") _
      & " the NewbieProof code module." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
      & "Please contact your local Code Guru." _
        , vbCritical
    Exit Sub
  End If

  '…

End Sub
```

---

If you want to keep everything in one module, using the same technique, you can place the following at the very top of the module, and have it loaded automatically into the spreadsheet:

```
' Fill this list with your desired values in the format:
' "'Cell = Value" (Remove the existing lines)

'C5 = "Hello"
'D6 = "World"
'E2 = 23.45
```

---

**Deal Breakers:**

- You **must** enable programmatic access to the VBA Project via `Developer > Code > Macro Security > Trust access to the VBA project object model`;
- The workbook **must** be unlocked (programmatically doing so is *only* able to be done by using the evil `SendKeys`).

**Features:**

- Basic fully functional error trapping is implemented;
- For duplicate Cells, the first one is used, the rest are discarded;
- Extra spaces are reasonably allowed anywhere but are not mandatory anywhere;
- Quotes are allowed around Cells;
- Quotes are *highly* recommended but not required around string Values (spaces between words can cause syntax errors);
- Quotes are allowed around number Values.

**Configuration:**

- The `NewbieProof` module name is changeable, but must be paired with the `l_NewbieProof` local constant;
- The `SuperNewieProofData` sub name is changeable without any impact;
- The `NewbieProof` module header is completely removeable;
- The `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3` reference is programatically added if required, as all VBIDE object access is early bound. This can be changed to suit your requirements.

---

> Note: If you are curious about my variable naming convention, it is based on [RVBA](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp).

Comment: This is great :) I have to go through it in detail to understand it all as I haven't programmed much in VBA. I can't have a newbie proof section if I don't understand the more advanced part of the code myself. I hope I'll be able to use this though, I just need some time...

Comment: @StewieGriffin Let me know if there's anything you don't understand or need help changing. I use a self-documenting style of variable naming, so have been a little sparse with actual comments. This is fairly advanced stuff, but still simple once you wrap your head around it.

Comment: Will do :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess this can be made simpler if `cell address` and `corresponding values` can be written somewhere in the sheet (columns that are not used). For example, if the cell address are entered in range `O1:O3` and corresponding values in range `P1:P3` then instead of

```
dict.Add "C5", "Hello"
dict.Add "D6", "World"
dict.Add "E2", 23.45
```

items can be added to dictionary as

```
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = Range("O1:O3")
For Each cel In rng
    dict.Add cel.Value, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next cel
```

and if number of rows will vary then above can be written as

```
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("O1:O" & lastRow)
For Each cel In rng
    dict.Add cel.Value, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next cel
```

---

Another way of doing this will be to add `cell address` in an array and `corresponding values` in another array as

```
Dim arr1, arr2, i As Long
arr1 = Array("C5", "D6", "E2")
arr2 = Array("Hello", "World", "23.45")
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    dict.Add arr1(i), arr2(i)
Next i
```

or adding both `cell address` and `corresponding values` together in one array as

```
Dim arr, i As Long
arr = Array("C5", "Hello", "D6", "World", "E2", "23.45")
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
    dict.Add arr(i), arr(i + 1)
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea. Unfortunately, I can't enter the information in the sheet the script will run in. This is a macro that will run on a bunch of different sheets, all on the same template. The purpose of the one of the scripts is to verify if certain cells contain the correct information. The purpose of the other is to insert values into said cells. We'll send the sheet to customers, so we don't want any "mess" laying around on different sheets. It's also cumbersome to delete a sheet afterwards. I have tried the VBA approach here earlier, but figured `dict.Add` would be a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get all info from the sheet, including the cell addresses

If you have on Sheet1:

> ```
> C5 = "Hello"
> D6 = "World"
> E2 = 23.45
> F3 = 13
> ```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NewbieProofSub()
    Dim d As Object, cel As Range, k As Variant, valid As String

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cel In Sheet1.UsedRange
        If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then d(cel.Address(False, False)) = cel.Value2
    Next

    d("F3") = 15      'Change dictionary value

    For Each k In d.Keys
        valid = IIf(Sheet1.Range(k).Value2 <> d(k), "not ", vbNullString)
        MsgBox "The value in " & k & " is " & valid & d(k)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

When you attempt to access a key in a dictionary

- If the key doesn't exist the new pair will be added to the dictionary silently
- Else it will not create a duplicate key, but its value will be updated

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea. Unfortunately, I can't enter the information in the sheet the script will run in. This is a macro that will run on a bunch of different sheets, all on the same template. The purpose of the one of the scripts is to verify if certain cells contain the correct information. The purpose of the other is to insert values into said cells. We'll send the sheet to customers, so we don't want any "mess" laying around on different sheets. It's also cumbersome to delete a sheet afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

On way to quickly load a dictionary would be to create a constructor named `Dictionary`, just like `Array`.

You could then load the dictionary with the keys/items aligned as arguments:

```
Set dict = Dictionary("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3)
```

, or with a range where the keys are in the first column and the items in the second:

```
Set dict = Dictionary([Sheet1!A2])
```

Here's function which allows the previous examples :

```
Public Function Dictionary(ParamArray args()) As Object
  Dim i As Long, arr()
  Set Dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  If UBound(args) >= 0 Then   ' if has arguments '
    If VBA.IsObject(args(0)) Then   ' if object then load a Range '
      arr = args(0).Resize(args(0).End(xlDown).Row - args(0).Row + 1, 2).Value

      For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Dictionary.Add arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)
      Next
    Else                               ' else load an Array '
      For i = 0 To UBound(args) Step 2
        Dictionary.Add args(i), args(i + 1)
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a good idea, and one I've tried before finding the approach I used in the question. Personally, I think the approach here is easy to understand. But for someone who's not used to data structures, the `key, argument, key, argument` approach will be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is declare a constant at the very top of your code. This way, a newbie is less likely to break the code.

You can use any character for either separator, except for <kbd>Space</kbd> for the first one and any character that ***may*** appear in a valid text value, for either.

I've shown a few ways to extract the cell-value pairs. Delete all the `If`s except for one, for the code to work:

```
' Fill this list with your desired values in the format:
' "=Cell Value" (Remove the existing lines)

Private Const NewbieProofString As String = "" _
& "=C5 Hello" _
& "=D6 World" _
& "=E2 23.45" _
' Don't remove this line

Sub NOT_NewbieProofSub()

  Dim varItem As Variant
  Dim astrItem() As String
  Dim lngSeparatorIndex  As Long
  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For Each varItem In Split(NewbieProofString, "=") ' First separator
      ' This if second separator = " "
    If varItem <> vbNullString Then ' First item is always empty
      lngSeparatorIndex = InStr(varItem, " ")
      dict.Add Left$(varItem, lngSeparatorIndex - 1), Trim(Mid$(varItem, lngSeparatorIndex)) ' Allows extra spaces between key and value
    End If
      ' Or alternatively this if second separator = " "
    If varItem <> vbNullString Then ' First item is always empty
      astrItem = Split(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(varItem, " ", "§", 1), "§") 'Use anything NOT EVER found in your values
      dict.Add astrItem(0), Trim(astrItem(1)) ' Allows extra spaces
    End If
      ' Or this if second separator anything else, e.g., ":"
    If varItem <> vbNullString Then ' First item is always empty
      astrItem = Split(varItem, ":")
      dict.Add astrItem(0), Trim(astrItem(1)) ' Allows extra spaces
    End If
  Next varItem

  …

End Sub
```

Note the special construction of the declaration so that every line of entered data is identical. This causes two side effects:

- There ***MUST*** be a comment, or blank line, immediately following the declaration;
- The first cell-value item wills always be empty.